# How to render plot from other packages such as DiagrammeR in R Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny, ggplotly

I'm trying to create a plot in Shiny, but it is not working. It is blank.
I think it is because `lavaanPlot` uses `DiagrammeR` svg graphics.

Here's the code

```
library(shiny)
library(lavaan)
library(lavaanPlot)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Text Input"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textAreaInput(inputId = "text1", 
                      label = "Syntax"), 
                      value = "Enter formula"),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("plot"),
           verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
           verbatimTextOutput("regout")
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  formula <- reactive({
    tryCatch({
      input$text1
    }, error = function(e) NULL)
  })
  model <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(formula()))
    tryCatch({
        cfa(formula(), data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
      }, error = function(e) NULL)
    })
  results <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(model())){
      summary(model(), fit.measures = TRUE)
    }
  }) 
  output$regout <- renderPrint({
      results()
    })
  plot2 <- reactive({
      lavaanPlot(model = model)
    })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot2
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm getting this error sometimes:

```
Error: trying to get slot "ParTable" from an object (class "reactiveExpr") that is not an S4 object
```

Comment: You call reactive objects as if they are functions. So inside your `output$plot` call, use `plot2()`.

Comment: TyperWriter, look for the reference to `dataInput()` in https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/

Comment: I tried, but it did not work using ```plot2()``` inside ```output$plot ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred to the plot as a function as recommended and then used `renderGrViz` and `grVizOutput` and it worked.

I did this:

```
output$plot2 <- renderGrViz({
      lavaanPlot(model = model())
    })
```

and this

```
grVizOutput("plot2", width = "50%", height = "100px")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ui.R codes of output plot is

`mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")`

but, in the server.R output$plot's name is  plot2,

`output$plot <- renderPlot({plot2......`

maybe the reason is on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that, but it did not work.

Comment: You need to call `model()` as a function in your `plot2` reactive as well..

Comment: `DiagrammeR` objects render correctly in Shiny.  I've done it many times.  As the other responders have indicated, the problem is in the way you are referencing your reactives.  You ned to call them as if they are functions.  Because, in fact, they are.